# C++ быстрые регулярные выражения

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, boost

нужно прогнать по тексту 2000 строк 200 регулярных выражений на совпадение.
какой движок дает наибольшую скорость ?

как оптимизировать настройку регулярных выражений С++ ?

Comment: Проблема здесь в том, чтобы создать репрезентативный тесткейс. Один алгоритм/библиотека может хорошо работать с длинными строками, другая делает быстрый бэктрекинг, третья быстрее всех, но отжирает гигабайт памяти при старте приложения и компилируется только под 32-бита, четвёртая в деструкторе тормозит две секунды, пятая единственная правильно поддерживает Unicode — какую считать лучше? Одни критерии важны для вас, другие для меня.

Comment: Есть еще такая штука. https://github.com/yandex/pire она очень хорошо подходит для таких задач- много регулярных выражений к одному тексту, но возможности весьма ограничены по сравнению с pcre.

Answer (score 6):

Нужно различать скорость в среднем и скорость в худшем случаях. Большинство современных движков регулярных выражений основаны на переборе с возвратом, поэтому в патологических случаях они работают за экспоненциальное время, и одно простое регулярное выражение на одной строке в какую-то сотню символов не завершится при вашей жизни. Но, хочу заметить, что такие патологические случаи в реальной жизни маловероятны. С другой стороны, если у вас нет контроля над входными данными (то есть они, например, поступают извне, от конечного пользователя), злоумышленник вполне может сделать такой случай реальностью.

Есть другой класс движков, ныне мало распространенных в библиотеках языков программирования, которые основаны на эмуляции конечных автоматов. Наиболее современная из относительно распространенных сейчас -- [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/) от Russ Cox. Более того, есть отличная [статья](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) от него же, которая раскрывает суть проблемы реализации движков регулярных выражений с помощью перебора с возвратом. Но опять же, на ваших данных эта библиотека может работать хуже, чем обычные движки, тут скорее вопрос, контролируете ли вы эти данные или нет. Ну и стоит учесть, что в `re2` не реализованы обратные ссылки (их добавление делает язык, описываемый "регулярными выражениями", не регулярным, поэтому эмуляцией конечных автоматов тут не обойтись).

В общем все довольно очевидно. Если вы полностью контролируете свои данные, то просто выберите пару-тройку самых распространенных библиотек, и проведите тестирование, какая работает лучше **на ваших** данных. Если же за входными данными контроля нет, то лучше выбрать ту же `re2`, которая эмулирует конечный автомат гарантированно работает за полиномиальное, а не экспоненциальное время.

Comment: под «классами движков» вы подразумеваете *nfa* и *dfa*?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не совсем. Если вы имеете ввиду классификацию по книге Фридла, то он в ней заблуждался. То, что он называет NFA (движки, основанные якобы на недетерменированных конечных автоматах) -- это на самом деле просто бэктрегинг, а то, что он называет DFA (на детерменированных конечных автоматах) -- это и есть движки, эмулирующие автоматы. Из регулярного выражения легко построить НКА, но редко его преобразуют целиком в ДКА, так как это очень затратно, обычно НКА эмулируют, а как именно, хорошо описано в указанной в моем ответе статье.

Comment: спасибо за информацию. а вот в [этой статье](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/RegularExpressionEngines) тоже неправильная классификация?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, она и есть из книги Фридла. Сама книга очень хорошая, но его рассуждения о механизмах реализации не верны, и классификация тоже (то есть классы в целом верны, просто называны неверно; то, что он называет NFA -- это бэктрегинг, а то, что DFA -- эмуляция автоматов, в том или ином виде). Очень рекомендую почитать статью Расса, станет все понятно.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что выходит: «мнение Расса против мнения Фриддла», «мнение практика против мнения теоретика»?

Comment: Не совсем. Расс -- практик-реализатор современного движка, написанного в рамках Google для проекта Code Search, а Фридл -- практик использования регулярных выражений, который написал по этой теме (теме использования оных) отличную (наверное, лучшую) книгу, немного оступившись и сместившись в одной из глав в тему, в которой оказался не совсем компетентен.

Comment: спасибо большое. не сможете подсказать, у кого, кроме Расса, можно почитать про критику компетентности Фриддла?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не знаю. Достаточно прочесть статью и посмотреть реализацию какой-либо из распространенных (стандартных) библиотек регулярных выражений, реализующей обратные ссылки, для Perl/Python/Ruby/Java/C (PCRE), основанной на том, что по Фридлу называется NFA. К автоматам это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: я вас понял, спасибо.